# Do I need to clear the statusbar before setting new content?

Tags: delphi

Does calling

```
Statusbar.Panels[0].Text := 'new text';
```

delete automatically the previous content of the status bar or do you have to first delete the previous content in code?

Comment: Any assignment (via `:=`) completely replaces the original data with the new data. This is very standard fundamentals of programming, and one of the very first things you should have learned.

Comment: Status bar does all the text paintjob for you, therefore, once you update the property, control will repaint itself with actual data. In contrast, owner-drawn panel does require you to erase background before drawing new content.

Comment: Seen many examples of clearing it beforehand that it made me wonder.So,whoever will post an answer ...

Comment: @JerryDodge You can do a lot of magic things with property setters, so it depends on the implementation. But you are right in this case and the current implementation.

Comment: It seems to me you could test this yourself in about 30 seconds with a new, blank application and a status bar. Is there a reason that you can't do so? And wouldn't that 30 seconds be even faster than the time you spent typing your question here and formatting the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying it would probably be faster than asking the question here :)

But yeah, the previous content gets cleared if you set a new text.

Your code doesn't immediately paint the text though, so if you're in a loop, you won't see the text being updated. If you want to force the painting of your new text, you could call `statusbar.repaint`. Just don't call it more than 10 times per second, else you'll notice that your loop slows down.